# Hive is not connecting with localhost:10000

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-18.04, beeline

I am trying to connect with hive localhost:10000 using the beeline with URL !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost: 10000. Both the client and the server running on the same machine. When I trying to run netstat -an | grep 10000 it gives nothing means the hive is not listening on 10000 port. please help why I beeline is not able to connect to the hive. I am able to connect using the url !connect jdbc:hive2// but not with the URL !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost: 10000 it gives me error 19/08/05 18:14:58 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

```
   <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
   <value>SASL</value>

   <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
   <value>10000</value>

   <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
   <value>127.0.0.1</value>
```